# String available check in for loop

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, for-loop

I have these cat breeds

```
cats = [
'Abyssinian',
'Balinese',
'Bombay',
'Birman'];
```

Now the code written is generally something like this

```
 for(var i in cats)
 {
  ... do
 }
```

Now I have to modify the same function in javascript. I can only modify to see if `i` is any of `Balinese` or `Bombay` .. then do these

I am thinking

```
 for(var i in cats)
 {
  if(i == 'Balinese' || i == 'Bombay'){
  ... do
  }
 }
```

Instead I would like something like `i` contains `Balinese,Bombay` instead of writing the `|` clause in middle?

```
 for(var i in cats)
 {
  if(i.contains('Balinese', 'Bombay'){   //this would be better, suggestions?
  ... do
  }
 }
```

How?

Comment: Whats `cat` here ? Also its `||` not `|`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: Also you need to mention type of your cat breeds if they are in array or object literal

Comment: `cats{ Abyssinian, Balinese, Bombay, Birman}` isn't valid syntax, seeing that all that follows builds on that, it's hard to guess which error you're trying to fix.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the logical OR operator is that much of a disturbance to you.

Comment: If jQuery is an option, this all comes down to about one line of code. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code,**

*This adds the .indexOf() in non-supported browsers*

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {  
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {  
        "use strict";  
        if (this == null) {  
            throw new TypeError();  
        }  
        var t = Object(this);  
        var len = t.length >>> 0;  
        if (len === 0) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        var n = 0;  
        if (arguments.length > 0) {  
            n = Number(arguments[1]);  
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN  
                n = 0;  
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {  
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));  
            }  
        }  
        if (n >= len) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);  
        for (; k < len; k++) {  
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {  
                return k;  
            }  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  
}
```

*Adding contains method in Array prototype*

```
 Array.prototype.contains = function(){ 
       for(var i=0,len=arguments.length;i<len;i++){
          if(this.indexOf(arguments[i]) !== -1){ 
              return true;
          } 
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Now, you can use like this,

```
var cats = [
'Abyssinian',
'Balinese',
'Bombay',
'Birman'];

if(cats.contains('Balinese')){
  console.log('Balinese');
}

if(cats.contains('Balinese','Bombay')){
  console.log('Balinese,Bombay');
}

if(cats.contains('lines','Bombay')){
  console.log('lines,Bombay');
}

if(cats.contains('lines','mbay')){
  console.log('lines,mbay');
}
```

If you are using jQuery, this code can be made simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Try nested loops?

```
var cats = ["Abyssinian", "Balinese", "Bombay", "Birman"];
var thisAndThat = ["Abyssinian", "Apple", "Siberian", "Windows", "StackOverflow"];

for(var i in cats) {
    for(var x in thisAndThat) {
        if(cats[i] == thisAndThat[x]){
            ... do
        }
    }
}
```

**With jQuery**

```
$.each(thisAndThat, function(key, value){
  if( $.inArray(value, cats) > -1 ){
    alert(value+" is inside the cats array.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Your array initialisation is wrong. Not `var cats[] = [a,b,c];` , but `var cats = [a,b,c];`

Comment: Oh man, this just isn't my day for JavaScript syntax. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

check this code,

```
var cats=['Abyssinian', 'Balinese', 'Bombay', 'Birman'];

Array.prototype.contains=function(incattype){

    for(var i=0; i<cats.length;i++){

        if(cats[i]==incattype) {
            return true;
        } else{
             return false;
        }      
    }
};


  var catslist=['Abyssinian', 'Balinese', 'Bombay11' ];

    for(var i=0; i<catslist.length;i++){

        document.write(cats.contains(catslist[i]));
    }
```

link;-

http://jsfiddle.net/fPdej/2/

Comment: why build a contains method, when there already is an [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)-method?

Answer (score 0):

First off, its important to realise that if you are traversing a javascript array with `for...in` then it is imperative that you use the `hasOwnProperty` method:

```
for(var i in cats){
    if(cats.hasOwnProperty(i))
        console.log(cats[i]);        
}
```

You really should be using `for(;;)` like so:

```
for(var i=0;i<cats.length;i++){
   console.log(cats[i]);
}
```

All that aside, you are looking for `Array.indexOf`, which is supported by modern browser but may have less support in older browsers - this is why most frameworks (jQuery, Moo, prototype etc) define their own variant of this method (See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript) for more detail).

```
var cats = ["Abyssinian","Balinese","Bombay","Birman"];

var test = ["Abyssinian","Balinese"];

for(var i in cats){
    if(cats.hasOwnProperty(i) && test.indexOf(cats[i]) != -1)
        console.log(cats[i]);        
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/4xJsg/

Answer (score 0):

It's not recomended to use for-in loops, because they are up to seven times slower than for, while or do-while ones. Instead of for-in, you can use for-each, too, which is not as faster as for or while but is more similar to for-in loops.

Combining it with regular expressions, my approach is:

```
var cats = [
    'Abyssinian',
    'Balinese',
    'Bombay',
    'Birman'
];

cats.forEach(function(cat, index){
    if(cat.match(/Abyssinian|Birman/)){
    // Do what you want
    }
});
```